# check variable in a file for consistency in increment

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, cygwin

I am using cygwin and have some experience writing scripts, using grep. it gave me the possibility to find  some particular strings in huge logfiles. 
Now I am facing a next challenge, but don't know how to solve it. Basically I want to check a number in a file, with the same number in a previous line. Consider the following file:

[image: Tracelog file]

the 2nd column in this message is a relative time in milliseconds.

I want to check the differences with the previous value. I want to display the occurences, where the differences  are greater than  50msec  (717 - 667 > 50)

Anyone knows how to do this? 
The way I have used grep is filter a complete file in a hole.  It is great and powerfull, but now I can't use it here.

Comment: You'd want to display both lines, or only the 2nd (too-large) one?

Comment: hi Jeff,  Only the 2nd is enough,  and stored in a file.

Comment: I want to check my huge logfiles,  to see if  serial communication has paused for a few seconds. This occurence is rare and happens only ounce in a million time. 
I expect to get a file with one or 2 occurences, or an empty file if everything is okay.

Answer (score 5):

That's a typical job for `awk`:

```
awk '$2 - prev > 50; {prev = $2}' < file
```

Or to only consider lines that have a number in the second field and skip the first line with a number:

```
awk 'prev != "" && $2 - prev > 50; $2 ~ /[0-9]/ {prev = $2}' < file
```

Comment: thanks,  I will test it.  Currently it prints every occurence, but will see how to fix it.

Comment: The following works for me:
 awk '$2 - prev > 65.000; { prev = $2 }' < $1

Comment: Is it possible to remove the first occurence from line 1  (value 667)?  This is not a real hit, but it will result in a hit, because the previous was a comment line

Comment: @Foppe, you did ask for a difference greater than 50, not 65. See edit for ignoring the first line.

Comment: yes but that's  just  fine tuning,    when using  50,   I get a number of occurences  that  differ  51 or 55 milliseconds.  But actually the timing for these messages was okay.   I want to filter out the occurences  where there was no message sent for 150 - 250 msec.   65  works fine for me now.